# How to store a cookie fetched by CURL such that it can be accessed by a page loaded in an iFrame

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, cookies, curl

I have a situation whereby when a page loads, I send some authentication data (in this case the associative array `$data`) which is verified by a script on another domain. Code below:

```
$cookie_path = 'cookies.txt';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.mysite.com/verify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

the site then sets a session (in this case I am using the codeigniter framework and sessions are set like:  `$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', true);` )

however when I load the external site in an iframe it does not seem to be able to detect that the session is set and redirects to the login page.

How do I ensure that my session cookie is being sent properly and can be accessed by an iframe?

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if Joe Hacker could randomly set a cookie for "yourbank.com" on your machine, while you're reading a page on "attackme.net". Imagine how much fun he could have with your accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curl script is running server side and storing the cookie for the second site there, but your browser is loading the second site in the client. You can share cookies across domains.

If you control the site you are attempting to create the session on, you may be able to pass the session ID to the PHP script, then generate the iframe URL dynamically, including the session ID as a query string, eg:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/php/php_mysql/Encoding_the_session_ID_as_a_GET_variable.html

*Edit*
To clarify, if you control the script on the second site, you can modify it to provide the SESSIONID of the authenticated session to your CURL script, which your PHP script making the cURL request can then incorporate into the dynamically generated iFrame src URL.

Comment: You can't share cookies across completely different domains.  That would be a huge security hole.  You can share cookies across different sub-domains though.  

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path

Comment: What you are suggesting is sharing data between servers.

Comment: So when cURL requests a URL, the page is loaded server side, and the cookie is stored on the generating server, not the requesting server as per normal?

Comment: The cookie will be stored on the machine making the request, in this case, the server making the cURL request. The problem is that you want to be authenticated on your client web browser, so you need to eschew the cookie model and tell domain within the iFrame that you are already authenticated through another means, such as including the SESSID in the iframe src URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can set cookies via:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

However, you can't set cookies for domains outside of your script's domain.